# How to I insert an id of associated table into a database

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have three table user, post and comment, post and comment are associate, post is a parent table and comment is a child table that has postId references post table, my problem is how to I insert a postId into a comment table where I have postId field, below is how I have tried but it did not work out. Please anyone who can help me.
my comment controller

```
    const models =require('../models/index');
exports.getAllComments=(req, res, next)=>{

    models.Comment.findAll({}).then((results)=>{
        res.status(200).json(results)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}
exports.getOneComment=(req, res) =>{
    const id =req.params.id
    models.Comment.findByPk(id).then((results) => res.json(results))
    }
exports.createComment=(req, res) => {
    models.Comment.create({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      PostId: req.body.PostId,
        include: [
          {
            model: models.Post,
            as: 'Post'
          }
        ]
    }).then()
    res.status(201).json({
      message:'Comment created successfully!!'
    });


}

exports.updateComment=(req, res) =>{
    const id =req.params.id
    models.Comment.update({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description

    },

    {
      where: {
        id: id
      }
    }).then()
         res.status(200).json({
           message:'Comment updated successfully!'
         })
    }
exports.deleteComment=(req, res) =>{
    const id =req.params.id;
    models.Comment.destroy({
      where: {
        id: id
      }
    }).then()
        res.status(200).json({
          message:'Comment deleted'
        })
    }
```

my post model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    author: DataTypes.STRING,
    content: DataTypes.TEXT,

  }, {});
  Post.associate = function(models) {
    // post hasMany comments
    Post.hasMany(models.Comment)
  };
  return Post;
};
```

my comment model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Comment = sequelize.define('Comment', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,


  }, {});
  Comment.associate = function(models) {
    // comments belongsTo Post
    Comment.belongsTo(models.Post)
  };
  return Comment;
};
```

Comment: You are doing it in reverse, Post needs to be created first and in create query comments need to be present.

Answer (score 0):

Try Bellow Code - Post will have many comments. 
Post Needs to be created first, in its association u need to send comments.

Define Relations with keyword - as - to make sure of the name of relation -

```
Comment.belongsTo(models.Post, { as: "post" });

Post.hasMany(models.Comment, { as: "comments" });
```

You can Define which key to use as foreign key as well in Sequelize -

```
Comment.belongsTo(models.Post, { as: "post", foreignKey: "postId", sourceKey: "id" });
```

Then use following to insert -

```
Post.create(
    {
        ...postData,
        comments: {
            title: req.body.title,
            description: req.body.description,
        }
    },
    {
        include: [
            {
                as: "comments",
                model: models.Comment
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

I have updated the solution but still it is not working , down is my post controller comment controller screen shot  and my models

postController

```
const models =require('../models/index');
exports.getAllPosts=(req, res, next)=>{

    models.Post.findAll({}).then((results)=>{
        res.status(200).json(results)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}
exports.getOnePost=(req, res) =>{
    const id =req.params.id
    models.Post.findByPk(id).then((results) => res.json(results))
    }
exports.createPost=(req, res) => {
    models.Post.create({
      title: req.body.title,
      author: req.body.author,
      content:req.body.content,
      comments: {
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
      },
        include: [
          {
            as: "comments",
            model: models.Comment
          }

        ]

    }).then()
    res.status(201).json({
      message:'Post created successfully!!'
    });


}

exports.updatePost=(req, res) =>{
    const id =req.params.id
    models.Post.update({
      title: req.body.title,
      author: req.body.author,
      content: req.body.content
    },

    {
      where: {
        id: id
      }
    }).then()
         res.status(200).json({
           message:'Post updated successfully!'
         })
    }
exports.deletePost=(req, res) =>{
    const id =req.params.id;
    models.Post.destroy({
      where: {
        id: id
      }
    }).then()
        res.status(200).json({
          message:'Post deleted'
        })
    }
```

commentController

```
const models =require('../models/index');
exports.getAllComments=(req, res, next)=>{

    models.Comment.findAll({}).then((results)=>{
        res.status(200).json(results)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}
exports.getOneComment=(req, res) =>{
    const id =req.params.id
    models.Comment.findByPk(id).then((results) => res.json(results))
    }
exports.createComment=(req, res) => {
    models.Comment.create({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,

    }).then()
    res.status(201).json({
      message:'Comment created successfully!!'
    });


}

exports.updateComment=(req, res) =>{
    const id =req.params.id
    models.Comment.update({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description

    },

    {
      where: {
        id: id
      }
    }).then()
         res.status(200).json({
           message:'Comment updated successfully!'
         })
    }
exports.deleteComment=(req, res) =>{
    const id =req.params.id;
    models.Comment.destroy({
      where: {
        id: id
      }
    }).then()
        res.status(200).json({
          message:'Comment deleted'
        })
    }
```

postModel

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    author: DataTypes.STRING,
    content: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Post.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Post.hasMany(models.Comment, { as: "comments" });
  };
  return Post;
};
```

comment Model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Comment = sequelize.define('Comment', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Comment.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Comment.belongsTo(models.Post, { as: "post", foreignKey: "postId", sourceKey: "id"});
  };
  return Comment;
};
```

screen shot when i run bd:migrate
[image]

Comment: It happened to me as well, there was an issue in the naming of relations. So the post was getting created but not comments.

Comment: the post was created as also before it was created but the issue it doesn't create a postId in comment table, that is what i need to fix

Comment: PostId: req.body.PostId, While creating post u have PostId in the capital. Sequelize normal behavior is to create the key as follows for the following - 
Comment.belongsTo(models.Post) = postId.

Comment: Rohit I did  as you suggested but still it didn't work, see i have uploaded the codes with your suggestion